# yii using $dataProvider and echo it in json array

Tags: php, json, yii

I want to make a *Web Service* for my site, I need to echo a *JSON* array

I am using this code:

```
 $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('AmakenPlaces',array(
                     'criteria'=>array(
                                                'condition'=>'admin_active=1',
                                )));
        $dataProvider->pagination->pageSize =10;
        $dataProvider->pagination->pageVar = 'page';
```

But how can U make the following:

```
echo CJSON::encode($dataProvider);
```

Echo a *JSON* array from my database ... I am using $dataProvider for pagination feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try calling the getData() method on your data provider:

```
echo CJSON::encode($dataProvider->getData());
```

Source: example at the top of http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveDataProvider

Comment: getData returns only a single row, or am I making a mistake?